# PostgreSQL Trigger to override insert on table with inheritance

Tags: postgresql, trigger, partitioning, postgresql-9.6, inheritance

We have a table `documents` that is partitioned by time into child tables like `documents_2019_01`, `documents_2019_02`. We do this using a `BEFORE` trigger on the parent `documents` table to insert into the correct child table and then return `NULL` to abort the pipeline so it is only inserted into the child table, though (you guessed it), this makes inserting documents a pain as you have to re-query for the created ids. We've looked into using an `INSTEAD OF` trigger type, but they cannot be applied to tables, only views.

Here is our current function used by the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_article_partition_and_insert() RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    partition_date TEXT;
    partition      TEXT;
    resultId       BIGINT;
BEGIN
    partition_date := to_char(NEW.updated, 'YYYY_MM');
    partition := TG_RELNAME || '_' || partition_date;
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname = partition)
    THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'A partition has been created %',partition;
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || partition || ' (LIKE ' || TG_RELNAME || ' INCLUDING ALL) INHERITS (' || TG_RELNAME ||
                '); ';
    END IF;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Inserting into %',partition;
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || partition || ' SELECT(' || TG_RELNAME || ' ' || quote_literal(NEW) || ').* RETURNING id;'
        INTO resultId;
    NEW.id := resultId;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

Is there a better way to partition inserts by time and return the inserted row of the child table without also inserting into the parent table?

Using PG version `9.6.11`.

Thank you!

[Cross-posting from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56245238)

Comment: whe you upgrade to postgres 11 you'll be able to use native partitioning instead of inheritance and this won't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks! We'll look into that but won't be able to upgrade for some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly use [`lastval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-sequence.html) or [`currval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-sequence.html) to get the last value from the sequence. or use [`nextval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-sequence.html) to get the id before the insert and then insert that value explicitly (instead of allowing the default value).

The third option is to ignore that column and instead use a natural key.  That you are able to get the ID by doing a select suggests that there is a natural key for this table.

Lastval and currval are private to your connection, so must be issued on the same connection that issued the insert.

Comment: Would race conditions not be an issue using these functions if we have multiple writes in parallel?

Comment: And also, even if using a transaction to potentially solve the race condition, how would this work for bulk insertions?

Comment: There are no race conditions to those functions beacuse they only see the results of actions in the session they are executed in (if you are using a connection pooler check the pooler documentation) ,  also sequences are unaffected by trasactuions.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Going to leave this open for a little bit longer to see if anyone else has any other solutions, but will accept this if not.